# how to change to list comprehension for below code in python

Tags: python

I need help with the list comprehension equivalent for the below normal loop code

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = []
for i in a :
    if i == 2 :
        b.append(i*2)
    else :
        b.append(i)

# the below list comprehension is filtering the list i don't know how to change it correctly
print([n*2 for n in a if n == 2 ] )

print(b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's "ternary" (I don't know the name of it)

```
[n*2 if n == 2 else n for n in a]
```

Comment: the python term is "conditional expression"

Answer (score 1):

Use an else statement, you need to put the for keyword at the end of the list comprehension:

```
[n*2 if n == 2 else n for n in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of doing it:

```
[n + n*(n==2) for n in a]
```